# How do i do segue after i finish picked an image from a gallery or camera?

Tags: ios, swift

How do i do a segue to another controller after i have done choosing a picture from a gallery or taking a picture from a camera phone?

Currently my **postChoices** view has 2 buttons that will take a user to a gallery or take a photo. I've done a segue in the storyboard if the user clicked the button it will bring it to the next view which is **postView**

but it doesn't work, it keeps going to the same view.

Here's the code

```
import UIKit

class postChoices: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {


    @IBAction func gallery(sender: AnyObject) {

        var image = UIImagePickerController()
        //image.delegate = self
        image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        image.allowsEditing = false

        self.presentViewController(image, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("gall", sender: self)

            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
        println("Image selected")
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            }


}
```

Edited version, i added the storyBoard

[image]

Comment: I recommend you to name you classes with a capital letter.

Comment: do you mean the identifier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good to see you again.
Try the following and check my example below:

1. Connect two segues from the ViewController (NOT the buttons) to the target ViewControllers
2. Assign these segues proper names as *Segue identifier* (I chose *firstSegue* and *secondSegue* in my example)
3. Drag one IBAction from each Button to your ViewController (*firstButtonpressed*, *secondButtonPressed*)
4. Implement a proper `prepareForSegue`method

**Example**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  @IBAction func firstButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("firstSegue", sender: self)
  }

  @IBAction func secondButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("secondSegue", sender: self)
  }

  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    switch segue.identifier!{
    case "firstSegue":  // Do stuff to prepare for first target VC
    case "secondSegue": // Do stuff to prepare for second target VC
    default: println("Segue not defined")
    }
  }
}
```

[image: segues]
[image: ibactions]

Get back to us, if you need help again.

**Transport image to TargetVC**

The code of the sending VC:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    switch segue.identifier!{
      case "firstSegue":
      let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! TargetVC
      destination.myImage = UIImage()
      case "secondSegue": // Do stuff to prepare for second target VC
      default: println("Segue not defined")
    }
}
```

**Receiving VC**

```
class TargetVC: UIViewController {
  var myImage : UIImage!
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, i still stumbled upon the same problem, here is the github repo for this specific project https://github.com/sinusGob/BasicIphoneApp2

Comment: I want bring the image from the view controller to another view Controller

Comment: Use the prepareforSegueMethde

Comment: Hey Thank you for your help, but can we chat? I'm still having a problem

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78201/discussion-between-gutenmorgenuhu-and-sinusgob

Answer (score 1):

You can use `performSegueWithIdentifier` method. Insure, that segue identifier is correct, and the segue leads to the proper controller.

```
func imagePickerController(
    picker: UIImagePickerController, 
    didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, 
    editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!)
{
    println("Image selected")
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueToAnotherController", sender: nil)
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it still taking to the same view which is postChoices controller

Comment: May be something wrong in storyboard? Can you attach screenshot to your question?

Comment: i got this as well at the console **window is not equal to <UIImagePickerController: 0x7fd0e0803600>'s view's window!**

Comment: Is this segue attached to the button or to the view controller?

Comment: it is attached to the button

Comment: If you use `performSegueWithIdentifier`, attach segue to the view controller. The problem is that you showing two view controllers at the same time.

Comment: I dont understand your answer, where you say that i'm showing two view controllers at the same time?